# Simple Threads Behaviour in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
/* Multiple Threads Executing
 * Author Myth17
 */

class T1 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int c=0;c<10;c++)
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" running....");
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int c=0;c<10;c++)
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" running....");
    }
}


class T3 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
    for(int c=0;c<10;c++)   
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" running....");    
    }
}

class Rt
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        T1 j1=new T1();
        T2 j2=new T2();
        T3 j3=new T3();

        Thread w1=new Thread(j1);
        w1.setName("S");
        Thread w2=new Thread(j2);
        w2.setName("N");
        Thread w3=new Thread(j3);
        w3.setName("M");

        w1.start();
        w2.start();
        w3.start();
    }
}
```

If the loop runs up to 3 in the three for loops, in Linux Java JVM each thread executes serially as SSSNNNMMM (9 lines).

I changed the loop to run up to 10 in each for loops. I was expecting 30 lines and a change in order. But strangely S never executes and program exits!!

Shouldn't S get its chance sooner or later? As what I have read is that apart from deamon threads JVM shuts only after user thread complete.

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/6646/69458021.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/6646/69458021.png)

Comment: Doesn't make sense, which JVM vendor?

Comment: By the way: why do you have T1, T2 and T3? They are absolutely identical. There's no need to create separate classes. You wouldn't even need separate instances, since your class doesn't have any state.

Comment: The code you posted prints each thread name 10 times (serially for me, but that's implementation dependent). Are you sure that that's the code you're running?

Comment: Yeag...I have 3 exactly similar jobs for 3 threads which is foolish :|

Comment: Uh, are you sure the "S" and some of the "N" lines aren't just scrolling out of the console window?

Comment: Try replacing your `println` lines with `System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName())` (note: `print` instead of `println`) to avoid the problem ZoogieZork mentioned.

Comment: Yeah....Checked in terminal...The lines have scrolled off :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you realize that there are **8 lines of N** in your output folder and **10 lines of M**. It seems that the output window just displays 18 lines. S runs but you cannot see it.

Can you try **incrementing** loop to **20** instead of 10. I guess you will just see **18 lines of M**.

(It seems that the problem is just not having a scroll bar on output window. Resize should work if exists.)

Comment: Checked...Lines scrolled off.. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your snippet neither of the threads are daemon. And until you set the threads as daemon via [Thread#setDaemon()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) all the threads will execute completely before the app exits.

Recheck your problem!!

Comment: the threads must be marked as user threads - `setDaemon(false)`, not as daemon threads. If threre are only daemon threads, the JVM will exit. The default already is to create user threads. (*ucuz*)

Answer (score 1):

This should have worked. You could put log in the `run()` methods or debug it using break points.

Answer (score 1):

You only have 18 lines showing in the window.

All of the "S" lines have scrolled off, as well as two of the "N" lines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code on a Windows Sun JVM 1.6 and as expected, I got 30 lines. What kind of JVM are you using?
All non daemon threads should finish before the JVM exists.